# Query/Filter a pandas df using a dict of lists

Tags: python, pandas

### **My problem**

I have a dict `d` that can be of varying length consisting of the following format:

```
d = {
  "foo": [
    50,
    100
  ],
  "bar": [
    5,
    10
  ]
}
```

Where the key is a column name and the value is a two length list for the min and max value of said column to filter a datframe `df` on. Thus, given the input above I'd like to filter `df.foo` between 50-100 and `df.bar` between 5-10.

### **What I have tried**

Of course, I could just hard code it like so:

```
df.loc[(df.list(d.items())[0][0] > list(d.items())[0][1][0]) & (df.list(d.items())[0][0] < list(d.items())[0][1][1]) ...]
```

etc, but the number of keys (columns to filter on) may vary and also this just incredibly ugly code. Is there a cleaner/vectorized way to do this?

### **Context**

I am building a streamlit app where a user can create n min max filters on a dataframe, and the format listed above is the format [streamlit's slider](https://docs.streamlit.io/library/api-reference/widgets/st.slider) returns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, one way using `pandas.Series.between`:

```
# sample
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(1234)

df = pd.DataFrame({"foo": np.random.random(10) * 100,
                   "bar": np.random.random(10) * 10})

         foo       bar
0  19.151945  3.578173
1  62.210877  5.009951
2  43.772774  6.834629
3  78.535858  7.127020
4  77.997581  3.702508
5  27.259261  5.611962
6  27.646426  5.030832
7  80.187218  0.137684
8  95.813935  7.728266
9  87.593263  8.826412
```

Code:

```
new_df = df[np.logical_and.reduce([df[k].between(*v) for k, v in d.items()])]
print(new_df)
```

Output:

```
         foo       bar
1  62.210877  5.009951
3  78.535858  7.127020
8  95.813935  7.728266
9  87.593263  8.826412
```

Validation: Works on any number of filters:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((10, 10)), columns=[*"abcdefghij"])
d = {c: [0.1, 0.9] for c in df}
new_df = df[np.logical_and.reduce([df[k].between(*v) for k, v in d.items()])]
print(new_df)
```

Comment: Worked until I came across an error when using multiple filters (more than 3)... `TypeError: logical_and() takes from 2 to 3 positional arguments but 4 were given`. Is there any way around this?

Comment: @bismo I've updated with `np.logical_and.reduce` to accommodate any number of filters. Give it a try :)

Answer (score 0):

I hope this works for your solution, I create a DataFrame for d and then i joined with another dataframe to match these values,

```
import pandas as pd
d = {
  "foo": [
    50,
    100
  ],
  "bar": [
    5,
    10
  ],
  "noto": [
      11,
      30
  ]
}
df_1 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "keys": d.keys(),
        "vals": d.values()
    }
)
df_1
df_2 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "item": ["foo", "bar", "noto"],
        "price": [65, 7, 33]
    }
)
main_df = df_1.merge(df_2, left_on='keys', right_on="item")
def check_price(x):
    return x['price'] >= x['vals'][0] and x['price'] <= x['vals'][1]
main_df[main_df.apply(lambda x: check_price(x), axis=1)]
```